# Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘PaymentPubKeyHash’ - Week 1 Pioneers Exercise

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

I'm trying to compile the week 1 code on plutus playground hosted locally, but I'm getting this error:

```
 error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘PaymentPubKeyHash’
   |
57 |     { aSeller   :: !PaymentPubKeyHash
   |   

              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is the code that originates the compilation error:

```
data Auction = Auction
    { aSeller   :: !PaymentPubKeyHash
    , aDeadline :: !POSIXTime
    , aMinBid   :: !Integer
    , aCurrency :: !CurrencySymbol
    , aToken    :: !TokenName
    } deriving (P.Show, Generic, ToJSON, FromJSON, ToSchema)
```

I have followed the steps on the week1 videos, but I'm getting this error, any help is welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: What gitrev of plutus-apps are you using? Can you gist your entire code file? I'm guessing either a version mismatch or a typo.

Comment: @SamuelLeathers I just got it working. I ran `cabal update` in the week1 code folder and the code compiled. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I was running the plutus playground on a old version of `plutus` repository not `plutus-apps`

Answer (score 0):

**import Ledger.Address qualified as Address          (Address, PaymentPubKeyHash(..))**

import PaymentPubKeyHash .